# Failed to build docker image in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins on an EC2 instance (Linux). Build test quality gates etc are working well but when it comes to build the docker image it fails with this error:

```
process "/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install maven -y" did not complete successfully
exit code 100
```

I tried to configure `dkpg` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please include the full error trace in your question. There should be logs about why it did fail during the build. Thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC4id.jpg.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUW6z.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph4ss.jpg

Comment: Please check the device space. While building docker it doesn't have space. The error says `No space left on the device`.

Comment: thnaks for the reply @DhavalGajjar. I cleaned up some space but still cant build the app img. below is the image for console output . thanks    https://ibb.co/L6Nxgw6

Comment: From the error, it seems you are using openjdk:8 image and while installing OpenJDK 11 it's having an error. What error it has not shown in the log? Why are you installing maven in the image and compiling code in docker? Instead, compile locally and copy output to an image.